# Retrieving JSONObject from API in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-asynctask

I am having an error in the method that retrieves the JSONObject and converts it to a string, the error says "!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

```
public class FindSentimentTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        String toReturn= "DID NOT WORK";
        try
        {
            toReturn=getResponseFromHttpUrl(url[0]);

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("ErrorInApp","exception on get Response from HTTP call" + e.getMessage());
            return toReturn;
        }

        return toReturn;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String sentimentData) {
        try {
            JSONObject sentimentJSON = new JSONObject(sentimentData);
            ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)).setText(sentimentJSON.toString());

            //String testOutput = sentimentJSON.get("docs").toString();
            //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)).setText(testOutput.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("ErrorInApp","exception in onPostExecute" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(String url) throws IOException {
    URL theURL = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) theURL.openConnection();
    try {
        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

More specificaly the error is here where I retrieve the JSONObject and turn it into a string to display in a TextView

```
protected void onPostExecute(String sentimentData) {
    try {
        JSONObject sentimentJSON = new JSONObject(sentimentData);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.output)).setText(sentimentJSON.toString());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("ErrorInApp","exception in onPostExecute" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The API I am using is https://developer.nytimes.com/article_search_v2.json

Comment: Your sentimentData is not json. It might be regular html returned from API side. Better to check contents of sentimentData.

Comment: so it seems to be outputting the actual web page in HTML not the JSON object, where am I going wrong? Or is the problem on NYT's end?

Comment: Looks like correct url should be `https://api.nytimes.com/svc/search/v2/articlesearch.json`. Your url is a description page.

Comment: Whats the url you are using? The endpoint you should use is /articlesearch.json?q=donald+trump for example.

Comment: you are using old process. You can use volley or retrofit. You should check is it json..